# fbgraph gem compatible with rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Is the fbgraph gem usable with rails 2.3.8?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/nsanta/fbgraph/issues/50

Per the author, it is framework agnostic.  It does seem to require the bundler gem with newer releases if using on Rails 2.

Answer (score 0):

No. As you can see, [on GitHub author has written](https://github.com/nsanta/fbgraph) "Facebook Open Graph API Gem **for Rails 3**."